# Array Representation of Polynomials

Tags: arrays, linked-list

I was reading about linked list implementation of polynomials. It stated,

```
Compare this representation with storing the same
polynomial using an array structure.
In the array we have to have keep a slot for each exponent
of x, thus if we have a polynomial of order 50 but containing
just 6 terms, then a large number of entries will be zero in
the array.
```

I was wondering how do we represent a polynomial in an array? Please guide me.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A complete Java implementation of array-based polynomials is here: [https://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/classes/dsa/assignment/2/answers/](https://cs.lmu.edu/%7Eray/classes/dsa/assignment/2/answers/)

The basic idea is that if you have a polynomial like

```
4x^6-2x+5
```

then your array would look like

```
   0     1    2    3    4    5    6
+----+-----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 5  |  -2 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  0 |  4 |
+----+-----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

That is

- the coefficient 5 is in slot 0 of the array (representing 5x^0)
- the coefficient -2 is in slot 1 of the array (representing -2x^1)
- the coefficient 4 is in slot 6 of the array (representing 4x^6)

You can probably see how this represenation would be wasteful for polynomials like

```
3x^5000 + 2
```

In cases like this you want instead to use a *sparse array* representation.  The simplest approach would be to use a map (dictionary) whose keys are the exponoents and whose values are the coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your polynomial is

```
6x^50 + 4x^2 + 2x + 1
```

The paragraph you have posted is describing storing it in an array like this:

```
polynomial = new array(50)  // I'm assuming all elements initialize to zero
polynomial[50] = 6
polynomial[2] = 4
polynomial[1] = 2
polynomial[0] = 1
```

Basically its wasting a lot of space this way. Here the array index is the 'power' of x for the polynomial in x.

Answer (score 1):

usually you hold one element for each exponent, so the polynom is actually: 

`poly[0]*x^0 +  poly[1]*x^1 + ... + poly[n-1]*x^(n-1)`

for example. if you have `p(x) = 3x^5+5x^2+1`, your array will be:

```
poly[0] = 1
poly[1] = 0
poly[2] = 5
poly[3] = 0
poly[4] = 0
poly[5] = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a polynomial function like

```
3x^4 + x^2 + 2x + 1 = 0
```

You can represent it in array as

```
[1 2 1 0 3]
```

So, the element 0 is the coefficient of x^0, element 1 is the coefficient of x^1 and so on...

Comment: So the index represents the exponent? Is this the reason why we need to represent all of the terms even if they don't exist in the polynomial?

Comment: Exactly. I think this is the most intuitive way to represent a polynomial in an array. :) In a polynomial "don't exist" means that it has coefficient 0. So you must store it in the corresponding slot of the array.

Comment: In general, you don't have to represent them all.  If the polynomial is sparse, use a dictionary instead of an array.  Your question, however, asked how to use an array.  Arrays are by definition contiguious, though, so if you want an array, you will need the zeros.